# Creating a list of matches that one team has played

Tags: postgresql, relational-database

I'm creating a database to hold football statistics, just one league. I want to create a list of matches that just one team has played, with 4 columns: selected team, their score, opponents score, and name of opponent.

My attempts at this have used these two tables:

(PKs in bold, FKs asterisk):

team(**team_id**, team_name, stadium)

match(**match_id**, home_team*, away_team*, home_score, away_score, gameweek)

My attempt looks like this:

```
(SELECT team_name, home_score, away_score
FROM team
INNER JOIN match
ON teams.team_id = match.home_team)
UNION
(SELECT team_name, away_score, home_score
FROM team
INNER JOIN match
ON team.team_id = match.away_team);
```

However, this returns duplicated results of each match, with both teams from a given match having an entry each.

How could I achieve this with my tables, or is it not possible?